# Show that for any graph $G$, there exists at least one vertex with odd number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that for any graph $G$, there exists at least 1 vertex with an odd number of edges.

${\textbf{Additional Requirement}}$:

One of the vertices must have an edge to a vertex "outside" $G$. Think of that "outside" edge being a way in to a city ($G$), or door to a house ($G$).

So, for instance of a house: The vertices are rooms and the edges are doors. There exists only one entrance (a door) in to the house.

I've thought about the case for a complete graph,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
 n&=2k+1, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+_0 \\
 K_n &\Rightarrow deg(n-1) \\
 &\Rightarrow deg(2k)\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
then we simply add the "outside" edge and vertex to one of the $n$ vertices, giving us a graph with one vertex having an odd number of edges.

But that does not apply to "any graph".

I'd really appreciate some guidance and help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the [Handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)?

Comment: I think your question needs to be refined a bit.  Specifically, is the edge from a vertex in G to a vertex outside of G considered to be an edge in G or not?  If that edge is not in G then you don't have to have a vertex with an odd number of edges (e.g. G could be a cycle).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I'm aware of the lemma, but don't see how I can use it, in other ways than proving that if there exists vertices with odd degree then there must exist an even number of odd vertices.

Comment: Add the "outside" vertex and the connecting edge to the graph G. That added vertex has degree 1. Then apply the lemma to this enlarged graph.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a graph with $n$ vertices, and $\mathcal{G'}$ be a subgraph with $n-1$ vertices such that the vertex in $\mathcal{G}\setminus\mathcal{G'}$ (the "outside") is connected to exactly one vertex in $\mathcal{G'}$. We want to show that there must be a vertex in $\mathcal{G'}$ with odd degree.

Let $v_0$ be the vertex which is connected to "the outside" by an edge, and for a contradiction suppose all $v \in \mathcal{G}$ have even degree.

This requires $v_0$ to have an odd number of connections in $\mathcal{G'}$, and all other vertices in $\mathcal{G'}$ to have even number of connections in $\mathcal{G'}$. This means the sum of degrees in $\mathcal{G}$ is odd - which is not possible since the total number of edges (an integer) is the sum of degrees divided by two.

So there must be at least one vertex in $\mathcal{G'}$ with odd degree.

Comment: Makes so much sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If every vertex in $G$ has an even number of edges, then the number of edge-ends in $G$ is even. But the unique edge going out of $G$ has only one edge-end, and every other edge has two, so the number of edge-ends in $G$ is even. A contradiction.